# Reducing the time complexity/Optimizing the solution

Tags: java, math

The motto is to find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below N.

Here's my code:

```
public class Solution
 {
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = in.nextInt();
    long n=0;
    long sum=0;

    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++)
    {
        n = in.nextInt();
        sum=0;
         for(long i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
        if(i%3==0 || i%5==0)

            sum = sum + i;
        }
   System.out.println(sum); 
    }
 }
}
```

It's taking more than 1sec to execute for some of the test cases. Can anyone please help me out so as to reduce the time complexity?

Comment: O(n) is the best you can get with this.

Comment: This problem has a trivial constant time solution, O(1)!

Comment: Read this [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9259/find-the-sum-of-all-the-multiples-of-3-or-5-below-1000](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9259/find-the-sum-of-all-the-multiples-of-3-or-5-below-1000).

Answer (score 1):

We can find the sum of all multiples of number `d` that are below `N` as a sum of an arithmetic progression (their sum is equal to `d + 2*d + 3*d + ...`).

```
long multiplesSum(long N, long d) {
    long highestMultiple = (N-1) / d * d;
    long numberOfMultiples = highestMultiple / d;
    return (d + highestMultiple) * numberOfMultiples / 2;
}
```

Then the result will be equal to:

```
long resultSum(long N) {
    return multiplesSum(N, 3) + multiplesSum(N, 5) - multiplesSum(N, 3*5);
}
```

We need to subtract `multiplesSum(N, 15)` because there are numbers that are multiples of both `3` and `5` and we added them twice.

Complexity: **O(1)**

Answer (score 0):

You can't reduce the time complexity in this case as there are still `O(N)` of each set of numbers. However you can reduce the *constant multiplier* by using integer division:

```
static int findMultiples(int N, int s)
{
    int c = N / s, sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0, k = s; i < c; i++, k += s)
        sum += k;
    return sum;
}
```

This way you only loop through the multiples themselves instead of the whole range [0, N].

Note that you will need to do `findMultiples(N, 3) + findMultiples(N, 5) - findMultiples(N, 15)`, to remove the duplicated multiples of both 3 and 5. The number of loops is therefore N/3 + N/5 + N/15 = 0.6N instead of N.

EDIT: in general the solution for an arbitrary number of divisors is `sum(findMultiples(N,divisor_i) - findMultiples(N,LCM(all_divisors))`; however it is only worth doing this if `sum(1/divisor_i) + 1/LCM(all_divisors) < 1`, otherwise there will be more loops. Luckily this will never be true for 2 divisors.

Comment: Sounds great! I'll try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The sum of all numbers from 1 to (including) N is known to be N(N+1)/2 (no need for iteration).

So, the sum of all multiples of K, from K to KM is K times the above formula, giving KM(M+1)/2.

Combine this with @meowgoesthedog's findMultiples(N, 3) + findMultiples(N, 5) - findMultiples(N, 15) idea, and you have a constant-time solution.

Answer (score -1):

A solution for your problem.Fastest method for solving your problem.

```
import java.util.*;
class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt();
        while(t!=0)
        {
            long a=in.nextLong();
            long q=a-1;
            long aa=q/3;
            long bb=q/5;
            long cc=q/15;
            long aaa=((aa*(aa+1))/2)*3;
            long bbb=((bb*(bb+1))/2)*5;
            long ccc=((cc*(cc+1))/2)*15;
            System.out.println(aaa+bbb-ccc);
         t-=1;}
    }
}
```

Comment: What reason behind answeris not usful ?